# Confluence: Is there a way to use space variables in Global PDF Stylesheet? Or somehow include it on PDF Exports

Tags: css, pdf, confluence, pdf-extraction

For PDF exports, I'm trying to export the space name to the bottom center of the export.

I tried the following but no luck so far:

```
@bottom-center
{
content: $space.getName();
}
```

I think the space variables do not work within the PDF CSS Stylesheet.

Is there another way of possibly achieving this?

I look forward to your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at our [Scroll PDF Exporter for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-pdf/server/overview).

Scroll PDF Exporter is an app for Confluence Server and Cloud that allows you to further customize your exports using a graphical template designer.

One key feature of the app is the possibility to use placeholders for specific metadata (e.g. the space name). Those placeholders can be used in the header or footer of your exported file and will be replaced during export with the wanted information.

You can find further information about all available placeholders in our [Scroll PDF Exporter documentation](https://help.k15t.com/scroll-pdf-exporter/latest/customize-document-sections-121932316.html#id-.Customizedocumentsectionsv4.0-placeholdersAddplaceholders).
For your specific use case the placeholder "Space Name" should work.

You can try out Scroll PDF Exporter using a 30 day trial license via the Atlassian Marketplace.
In case you have any further questions regarding the app, please get in touch with us via support[at]k15t.com.

We'll be happy to help.

Best,
Nils